# how to convert calendar object to a specific time zone

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-calendar, android-date

I am getting date from database from time-zone A (dBDate) and I am getting the current date from my android device I am currently using in time-zone B (deviceNowDate), I need to find the difference between the 2 dates in milli seconds so I think I should convert both of these dates to 1 hardcoded timezone (say timezone C) and then find the difference. How do I convert both of these dates to another time zone?

They are calendar objects.

```
dbDate.setTimeZone();
```

will this change the time zone and also convert the date/time for me?

Comment: If both date from DB and your device already in `Calendar` instance with correct timezone set, then I think you can just use `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` to get the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.

Comment: thats the problem, my DB is using America/New_York time zone however my device is in EST time zone

Comment: How do you store the date in DB? Is it in UTC milliseconds? Or text format? `setTimeZone()` only change the timezone representation of the `Calendar`. (e.g. from `2013-10-30T00:00:00-03:00` to `2013-10-30T02:00:00-01:00`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the date stored in the database is already in UTC, you can just use the value right away. Or the alternative way is to get a `Calendar` instance and set the time in milliseconds using `setTimeInMillis(long millis)`.

For the current date & time on the device, invoking `Calendar.getInstance()` will return a `Calendar` with device's time zone, date and time.

The `getTimeInMillis()` will return the UTC milliseconds from epoch, which is independent of the time zone.

Try

```
long dbMillis = ... // get date value from DB, in UTC already

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // get device's date time with
                                       // default device time zone
long now = cal.getTimeInMillis(); // returns device's date time in UTC

long diff = Math.abs(now - dbMillis);
```

Comment: so Calendar.getInstance(); gives you the device date time in UTC? or does getTimeInMillis() give you UTC time?

Comment: `getInstance()` gives device date with default (device) time zone. `getTimeInMillis()` gives UTC time.